# how do i extract values from multiple divs with xpath

Tags: php, xpath

How do I make this code snippet return the values for every `div` with class `age` on the page I am parsing rather than just the first one as it does now?

```
$nodelist = $xpath->query('//div[@class="age"]')->item(0);
print_r($nodelist->nodeValue);
```

I have some similar code that returns all the images I want but I can't seem to modify it to return the matching `div` values I want:

```
$nodelist = $xpath->query( "//div[@class='thumb-wrapper']" );

foreach ($nodelist as $node) 
{
    $tags = $node->getElementsByTagName('img');
    $image =  $tags->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
    echo '<img src="'. $image .'" alt="image" ><br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ["*"](http://webdesign.about.com/library/weekly/aa110501a.htm)

> Using the star (*) selects every element that is within the preceding
>   path. So if you wanted to match every element that is within a td tag
>   (such as p, div, etc.), you would write: //td/*

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this code isn't the XPath its what you do with it once its returned.

```
$nodelist = $xpath->query('//div[@class="age"]')->item(0);
print_r($nodelist->nodeValue);
```

This gets all of the `div`s and then gets the first one using `->item(0)` and then assigns that frst item to the variable `$nodelist`.

Using you existing code as an example you can alter it by removing the `->item(0)`, assign all the results to `$nodelist` and iterate through them just like the second 'working' example:

```
$nodelist = $xpath->query('//div[@class="age"]');
foreach ($nodelist as $node) 
{
    // Do something with each div
}
```

Comment: I had something like that before but got nothing out of it. Maybe what I did with the `div` was wrong?